# How to print incoming http request on specific port

Tags: linux, http, ubuntu, tcpdump

I have a device that sends an HTTP request on my Linux server. I want to see all incoming requests format that comes from this device to the Linux HTTP server on a specific port. I have tried this by using Tcpdump but it seems to be not human-readable which difficult to understand what kind of HTTP request this device sends. Is there any command/tool which I can use on the ubuntu server to track this kind of info?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it will be closed on the StackOverflow, but it would be likely ontopic on the https://unix.stackexchange.com .

Answer (score 7):

I use tcpdump for capturing the data and [wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) on my notebook to inspect it:

```
sudo tcpdump -ni any port 80 -vv -s0 -w http.pcap
```

Some info:

```
-n: don't convert hosts, ports to names
-i any: capture on all interfaces
-vv: verbose output to see packet count
-s0: capture whole packet
-w http.pcap: write to file
```

Once you've collected enough data just hit Ctrl + C, and open the file using wireshark.

While you may be able to get some info with `tcpdump` alone using

```
-A     Print each packet (minus its link level header) in ASCII.  Handy for capturing web pages
```

that will only get you so far.