# How to implement auto stop for iddle or inactive applications on Google cloud platform like Heroku does?

Tags: heroku, google-cloud-platform, continuous-integration, devops

Classic approach on GCP is rent a linux host with static monthly payment. It doesn't matter if your application is not running or users aren't consuming it, you will always pay the static monthly payment. I think this is acceptable for **production** environments but for development and testing not.

This does not happen on [Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/free-dyno-hours#dyno-sleeping) :

> If an app has a free web dyno, and that dyno receives no web traffic in a 30-minute period, it will sleep. In addition to the web dyno sleeping, the worker dyno (if present) will also sleep.
> Free web dynos do not consume free dyno hours while sleeping.

**Question**

How stop or delete app on google (gae, cloud run, cloud build, containers) if does not receive web traffic?

If it is possible using just google tools it would be great:

- https://cloud.google.com/products

**Idea**

Developing a basic router with nodejs which works as minimal balancer. If web traffic is not detected for some apps, an instruction to google cloud platform api could stop the app or container. This would also apply to other clouds.

Any help is appreciated.

### Update

I cannot find any solution yet. I will try to add that feature here https://github.com/jrichardsz/http-operator or a basic shell script to detect incoming request to a specific port like [How to print incoming http request on specific port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52575549/how-to-print-incoming-http-request-on-specific-port)

Answer (score 0):

GCP is offering several [serverless products](https://cloud.google.com/serverless) (like you mentioned) and they offer a pricing where you are only charged for the resources you use (when requests are processed).

- In Cloud Run you are only billed when an instance is handling a
  request using the [autoscaling](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/about-instance-autoscaling) to know more. See their [pricing](https://cloud.google.com/run/pricing#cloudrun-pricing) as well for a better overview.
- For [Google App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/how-instances-are-managed#scaling_dynamic_instances) the app.yaml configuration file contains several settings you can use to adjust the trade-off between performance and resource load for a specific version of your app. You
  also check this [link](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/console/managing-resources#change_auto_scaling_performance_settings) how to manage the auto scaling settings.

You can also check this [Google Cloud blog](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/serverless/6-strategies-for-scaling-your-serverless-applications) for other strategies in auto scaling your applications.

To answer the Comment below:

This [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wzPmgWJ5fpU&feature=youtu.be) can help you better understand their differences to be able to see the appropriate service for your use case.

To clarify, there's 2 variations of cloud run, the first is managed by google and the other runs on gke. As long as your classic application (api app) is stateless, you should be able to deploy it as a container and take advantage of being charged based on only the resources you use. Snippets would fall under Cloud function where it only runs functions based on triggers.

You can choose to deploy your Cloud Run app on fully managed infrastructure ("serverless", pay per use, auto-scaling up rapidly and down to 0 depending on traffic) or on a Google Kubernetes Engine cluster.

It is also possible to run Docker containers in Serverless using App Engine (Flexible).  App Engine is always fully managed, with auto-scaling. App Engine Flex auto-scales gradually and down to 1. App Engine Second Generation auto-scales up rapidly and down to 0.

In your current use case I would recommend to use Cloud Run, check its limitations first before getting started. See the official documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs) and on Cloud Run [How-To Guides](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/how-to)

Comment: Thanks for your time. In my case I need to have classic app like : java api, python api, etc #1 Can I run a classic app in cloud run? #2 or is only for snippets? #2 Can I run a docker container in a serverless? #3 I think is not possible with serverless options. For that google offer classic linux host or the recent cloud run. In both of these options, if my app is running but it is not being used, I'll still pay.

Comment: I've updated my post above to answer a few of the questions, I would recommend seeing the video for a better explanation.

Comment: If my web needs to invoke for example 2 endpoints of my api which is hosted as docker container in Serverless App Engine, api will die after each invocation(two in my case) or stays awake after first invocation, so in the next invocation api will already be started ? Thanks for sharing me your knowledge :)